# How to set -webkit-clip-path as an attribute?

Tags: css, xml, d3.js, svg

I wrote some code that works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. It happens that instead of using the `clip-path` attribute, I must use `-webkit-clip-path`. However, when I try to set this attribute in D3, I get an error with the `setAttribute` function. Example:

```
this._path = this._curve.insert('path')
    .attr('d', this._line(chronicle))
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("-wekbit-clip-path", "url(#clip)") // ERROR HERE
    .attr("class", "curve")
    .attr("stroke", "orange");
```

The error is: `InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters.`

I have found that vendor prefixes have a special name when you use them in JavaScript. But using that special name in the `.attr` function does not translate into `-vendor-attribute` in the generated HTML.

So how can you set vendor prefixed attributes (`-webkit-clip-path` specifically) in D3 with the `.attr` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it this way for technical reasons, be it with vanilla JS, D3, or any other tool. By using [`.attr()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) you are trying to create an attribute having the name `-wekbit-clip-path`. However, with SVG being an XML grammar, the *XML name production* rules apply. For XML [attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#attdecls) the [name start character](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameStartChar) is defined as:

```
NameStartChar  ::=  ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] |
                    [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] |
                    [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
                    [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

This rules out the use of a hyphen (`-`) as the start character as you are trying to do.

The solution is fairly simple, though, just set it as a style property using [`.style()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_style):

```
this._path = this._curve.insert('path')
  .attr('d', this._line(chronicle))
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .style("-wekbit-clip-path", "url(#clip)") // set as a style property
  .attr("class", "curve")
  .attr("stroke", "orange");
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I could figured this out by myself :-). It does not work anyway: it seems that D3 checks the validity of attributes. If I type `.style("stroke", "red")`, I can find the styling in the generated elements (using the navigator's inspector). If I type `.style("foothebar", "red")`, nothing happens. Same thing for `.style("-wekbit-clip-path", "url(#clip)")`... I keep ugly my workaround, I style directly in the HTML file containing the SVG canvas.